# escaping single quotes using regexp_replace

Tags: regex, oracle11g

I need to replace any special characters with a space from an input column. Also, additionally,  need to suppress any single quotes as well.

I tried this that worked in replacing the special characters, but, it wouldn't suppress the single quotes however.

Input string from a database column:
'SEE'S CANDY?SHOPS INCORPORATED'

If I dont consider single quotes, then \W works to satisfy the first condition.

```
select regexp_replace('SEES CANDY?SHOPS INCORPORATED', '\W', ' ') from dual;

Output: SEES CANDY SHOPS INCORPORATED
```

However, outout required:

SEES CANDY SHOPS INCORPORATED while considering single quotes by escaping/suppressing it.

Comment: fyi doubling a single quote escapes the second quote in sql. Escaping with \\ does not. For everyone who come here looking for that answer (like me lol).

Answer (score 3):

```
select regexp_replace('SEES''CANDY?SHOPS_INCORPORATED123', '[^[:alnum:]''_]', ' ') from dual;
```

`[:alnum:]` Alphanumeric characters. Includes letters and numbers.

`\W` A nonword character (not a letter, not a number, not an underscore).

Remove single quotes then replace \W with a space:

```
select regexp_replace(replace(s, ''''), '\W', ' ') 
from (select q'[SEE'S candy?shops_incorporated123]' s from dual);
```

`q'[]'` is just an Oracle quote operator (lets you use single quotes inside the brackets without doubling them in order to escape)

Comment: Thanks. But, you are manipulating the inout string by ading a single quote which ofcourse will work. The input is from a database column. is there a way to programatically do this by first suppressing the single quotes.

Comment: @Casey I don't get your question then. I thought you need to replace all \W except a single quote. So you need to remove all single quotes and then replace other special symbols with a space. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. Single quotes quotes should be gone as well except they should just be suppressed. In the above example, SEE'S should just become SEES. The next step would be to use \W to replace special characters with a space as I have done earlier.

Comment: Thanks. But, it works when I use it with dual. But, I am probably messing it up when I add it to an input column. Tried this, but didn't work: select replace('q'['|| <input_column> || ']','''') from table_A; It prints the q[ as well.

Comment: @Casey You need only this: "select regexp_replace(replace(YOUR_COLUMN_NAME, ''''), '\W', ' ') from YOUR_TABLE"